# How to override CXF AbstractInvoker?

Tags: java, cxf, cxfrs

I've requirement where in my input request I'm getting parameters which are password thats needs to be masked Since I've kept logging level as debug, the input xml is getting logged with password fields. I fixed this problem by overriding LogginginInterceptors and LoggingOutInterceptor.

However on further analysis, found that  Abstract invoker is printing method invoked along with parameters for the method invoked. Hence password field is again getting printed. I can override the method which prints parameter. But where and how I need to register my my custom abstractmethod invoker.

```
2014-04-03 20:16:54,827 [http-8443-1] DEBUG o.a.c.s.invoker.AbstractInvoker - Invoking method public com.kp.schema.CredResObject com.kp.CredentialsImpl.updateCredentials(com.kp.schema.CredReqObject) throws com.kp.FaultResponse on object com.kp.CredentialsImpl@2ee4e8 with params [CredReqObject [clientID=kpid, host=asda, userName=u1, passWord=sssss]].
```

Custom Invoker

```
public class NMSCustomInvoker extends AbstractInvoker {

    static final ResourceBundle BUNDLE = BundleUtils
            .getBundle(FactoryInvoker.class);

    private Factory factory;

    public NMSCustomInvoker(Factory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public NMSCustomInvoker() {
    }

    public void setFactory(Factory f) {
        this.factory = f;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getServiceObject(Exchange ex) {
        try {
            return factory.create(ex);
        } catch (Fault e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new Fault(new Message("CREATE_SERVICE_OBJECT_EXC", BUNDLE), e);
        }
    }

    public void releaseServiceObject(final Exchange ex, Object obj) {
        factory.release(ex, obj);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object performInvocation(Exchange exchange,
            final Object serviceObject, Method m, Object[] paramArray)
            throws Exception {
        paramArray = insertExchange(m, paramArray, exchange);
        return m.invoke(serviceObject, paramArray);
    }

}
```

I'm getinng null pointer error since factory object is null.

Updated StackTrace

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not instantiate service object.
    at mypackage.NMSCustomInvoker.getServiceObject(NMSCustomInvoker.java:45) ~[NMSCustomInvoker.class:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:50) ~[cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) ~[cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94) ~[cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:167) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:211) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1.jar:3.0-alpha-1]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293) [catalina.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489) [tomcat-coyote.jar:6.0.37]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [na:1.6.0_32]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at mypackage.NMSCustomInvoker.getServiceObject(NMSCustomInvoker.java:41) ~[NMSCustomInvoker.class:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the invoker yourself if you are using cxf-jaxws or cxf-jaxrs front end API, just like this

```
ServerFactoryBean.setInvoker(new MyInvoker());
```

If you are using spring configuration, you can set your custom invoker just like this

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="simpleWithBinding"
    implementor="#greeter" 
        address="http://localhost:8080/simpleWithAddress">
    <jaxws:invoker>
       <bean id="myInvoker" class="com.example.MyInvoker"/>
    </jaxws:invoker>
  </jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: I had tried using custom invoker. But I'm getting null pointer error for factory object. Not sure how to pass instance of factory. Added my CustomInvoker